# Intro to programing Homework for C

Tags: c

In my intro to programming assignment I am having an issue with a problem. I have to create a shipping calculator that will ship your package based on how much it weighs and how far you are sending the package.  They will only ship packages up to 10 pounds.

The charges are based on each 500 miles shipped.  They are not pro-rated, i.e., 600 miles is the same charge as 900 miles, i.e.,  600 miles is counted as 2 segments of 500 miles.

Here is the table they gave me:

Package Weight                                            Rate per 500 miles shipped
2 pounds or less                $1.50
More than 2 but not more than 6     $3.70
More than 6 but not more than 10        $5.25

The problem is everytime I enter:

Weight: 1.0
Miles: 2000

I get $58.50 when it's suppose to be $6.00. Here is my code below. BTW i can't use loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    float weight, shippingCharge;
    int miles, mTotal, mModule, fTotal;

    printf("Weight: ");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    printf("Miles: ");
    scanf("%d", &miles);


        mTotal = miles / 500;
        mModule = miles % 500;

    if(mModule > 0){
        fTotal = mTotal + 1;
    }

    if( weight <= 2){
        shippingCharge = fTotal * 1.50;
        printf("Your shipping charge is $%.2f\n", shippingCharge);
    }else{
        if(weight >= 2 && weight <= 6){
            shippingCharge = fTotal * 3.70;
            printf("Your shipping charge is $%.2f\n", shippingCharge);
        }else{
            if(weight >= 6 && weight <= 10){
                shippingCharge = fTotal * 5.25;
                printf("Your shipping charge is $%.2f\n", shippingCharge);
            }else{
                printf("Sorry, we only ship packages of 10 pounds or less.");
            }
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use GDB the debugger for c, it will tell you exactly what is happening

Comment: `fTotal`  has no value assigned in that case, so you get an arbitrary value

Comment: There is a lot of useless code.

Comment: 1.How do i use the debugger in codeblocks?

2. how is ftotal arbitary when mTotal is assigned to it?

Comment: Because it's only assigned if `mModule > 0`, and `mModule` is only greater than 0 if `mMiles % 500 != 0`. `2000 % 500 == 0`, so `mModule = 0`, and therefore the `if (mModule > 0)` test never passes. *Always* initialize values before using them; don't depend on a test passing a condition to initialize it for you.

Comment: I don't think this questions has anything to do with a real programming issue at all. It's just a constuctive mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You do not initialise `fTotal` if the distance is an exact multiple of 500 - you need to set it to `mTotal` in that case.

So change:

```
if(mModule > 0){
    fTotal = mTotal + 1;
}
```

To this (for example):

```
fTotal = mTotal + (mModule > 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

An approach without using ternary operators:

```
if(mModule > 0) {
    fTotal = mTotal + 1;
} else {
    fTotal = mTotal; 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what that code means. can you break it down for me?

Comment: @user3799479 If `mModule` is greater than `0`, then `fTotal` would equal `mModule + 1` or else it would only equal `mModule`.

Comment: if(mModule > 0 ){
            fTotal = mTotal + 1;
        }else{
             fTotal == mTotal;
    } << like this?. I just tried this and got the same answer which above.

Comment: OMG I love you. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: @user3799479 not `fTotal == mTotal`, it should be `fTotal = mTotal`, with only one `=`.

Comment: `... + (mModule > 0) ? 1 : 0;` can logically be reduced to `... + (mModule > 0);`.  If comparison is true, adds 1, else 0.  (just an observation, and I see you provided an alternate)